Dreamweaver is not asking to update files when they are moved
I have a strange issue. If I import a site that someone else has made, everything works well, however if I try to rearrange the folder structure from within Dreamweaver, then it does not update the links, even though it is set to do so in the preferences.
If I create a new file, set up a new site, and then create it from scratch on this computer, I can move the files around, Dreamweaver is happy to update the links.
Is there something I've missed when importing/ defining a site?

Try clearing the cache! Most probably it is corrupted.
First close Dreamweaver. Then type %appdata% into the File Explorer address bar and hit Enter. Then navigate to the Adobe folder.
Inside the Adobe folder, find and open the Dreamweaver folder. Then, delete the cache files.
The cache files may be in a folder labeled ‘Cache’ or ‘Temp’. You can safely delete these files as they will be recreated by the software when needed.
